# Difficulty rendering form inside a loop

Tags: forms, rendering, web.py

I'm new to web.py and am having difficulty with the following:

in app.py

```
args = ()
for i in range(4):
    args = args + (form.Checkbox('followup'+str(i)), )

my_form = form.Form(*args)
```

in my_template.html

```
$for i in range(4):
    $ name = "followup"+ str(i)
    $name $:form.$name.render() <br>
```

when I run this I get the following error:

**'str' object has no attribute 'render'**

How should I change my template so that I will have 4 checkboxes?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `$:form.$name` resolves to a string, prior to the call to `render()`. You can fix that by replacing it with `$:form[name]`. You're still in the "python" context with `form[name]`, so you should use `name` rather than `$name`.

```
=== my_template.html ===
$def with(form)

$for i in range(4):
    $ name = 'followup' + str(i)
    $name $:form[name].render()<br/>
```

or, even simpler:

```
=== my_template.html ===
$def with(form)

$for i in form.inputs:
    $i.description $:i.render()<br/>
```

Comment: Thanks. It was the _$:form[name].render()_ that I needed.